# For a subspace $E \subset V$ and a linear functional $f \in E^{*}$ with $||f||=1$ there is a extension $g \in span\{v, E\}^{*}$ where $v \not \in E$

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, hahn-banach-theorem

Let $V$ be a normic space and $E \subset V$ a subspace. Let $v \in V \setminus E$. Let $f \in E^{*}$ be a bounded functional such that $||f||=1$.

I declare $W = span\{v,E\}$ and want to show that there is $g \in W^{*}$ such that $g|_E = f$ and $||g||=1$.

I started by taking $x \in W$, then there is a scalar $\lambda$ and $e \in E$ such that $x = \lambda v + e$ and such $\lambda$ and $e$ are unique.

Then I declared the functional $g(x) = g(\lambda v + e) = \lambda + f(e)$.

If $x \in E$ then $\lambda = 0$ so we get $g(x) = g(e) = f(e)$ concluding that $g|_E = f$. The only thing left is to show that $||g||=1$.

I managed to get $||g||\ge1$ since
$$sup_{||\lambda v + e||=1} |g(\lambda v + e)| = sup_{||\lambda v + e||=1} |\lambda + f(e)| \ge sup_{||e||=1} |f(e)| = ||f|| = 1$$

However, I couldn't get the inequality $||g|| \le 1$.

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: $E$ is a subspace of $W$, so by Hahn-Banach you can extend $f$ to a bounded functional on $W$ with the same norm. If you are allowed to use Hahn-Banach theorem then you don't have to prove anything in this exercise...

Comment: Okay, then probably the use of Hahn-Banach Theorem is not allowed.

Comment: Gabi is attempting to show the most crucial step in the proof of Hahn-Banach so it is surely inappropriate to use Hahn-Banach for that. Any book in functional analysis will have that proof but if the OP can't find it, I can point one out.

Comment: I did find it in a book, but there they declare $g(x) = \lambda c + f(e)$ for some specific $c$. I guess there is no way to solve it the way I declared $g$.